# Alternative proof that $\mathbb{Q}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

I was reading Rudin's proof that $\mathbb{Q}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$ and was thinking of a more intuitive proof.

I had a go at a proof, and I realised that there are probably many holes and hidden assumptions in it. I would be grateful if I could receive criticisms of the proof, so that I may make it more rigorous.

**"Proof"**

Let $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$ with $y>x$.

Note that $y-x$ is the distance of $x$ from $y$ on the real number line.

Choose $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and let  $k=n(y-x)$.

As $n$ increases, the distance $k$ along the real number line from $ny$ to $nx$ is gradually increased.

Choose a value of $n$ such that there exists an $m \in \mathbb{Z}$, with $nx<m<ny$ and so there exists a rational number $\frac{m}{n}$ such that $x<\frac{m}{n}<y$*

Comment: What you show is essentially: Between two different real numbers there is a rational number. This is not the standard defintion of a dense subset. So you need at least an additional step.

Comment: @gammatester In Rudin's book it is stated that "Q is dense in R" means "Betwwen any two real numbers is a rational one". That is the definition I am using...?

Comment: This is what it means to be dense as an ordered set. The definition for a topological space is a bit different, but in this case it is equivalent (of course it must be proved, but it's not diffucult).

Comment: @CaptainLama Sorry I haven't got to that chapter yet.

Comment: That's ok, you can take this definition of "dense" for now, and you will naturally see how it implies the topological one when you learn it.

Comment: Thanks for this; I find this much more understandable than Rudin's proof. I have an alteration that I think would make what you write clearer — you say "choose a value of $n$ such that there exists an $m \in \mathbb{Z}$ with ... and so there exists a rational number $\frac{m}{n}$ such that ..." but this sounds like we need to somehow find a number that happens to suit both conditions. Actually all we need to do is find $m$ with $nx < m < ny$ and then we can divide to get $\frac{m}{n}$ which suits the second condition.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know Rudin's proof, but this one is correct and quite standard.

The only thing it uses is that $\mathbb{R}$ is *archimedian*, meaning that for every $a,b>0$ there exists $n\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $na>b$. You use that when you say that there is $n$ such that $n(y-x)>1$ so there must be an integer between $nx$ and $ny$.

(You also have to know that there is an integer between two numbers $a,b$ such that $|a-b|>1$).

Comment: How would you prove the result in the parentheses?

Comment: use archimedian property and contradiction

Comment: Yes, you may consider the smallest integer that is strictly superior to $a$ (assuming $a<b$), which exists precisely because $\mathbb{R}$ is archimedian.

Comment: @Neel Thanks I understand now.

Comment: you're welcome.. :)